# Add event handler to graphics figure painted

Tags: vb.net, winforms, graphics

I know I can add event handlers to buttons, labels and textboxes like this:

```
AddHandler button1.click , AddressOf Subbutton1_click
```

I can actually draw a circle, ellipse, rectangle or another figure using graphics inside the Form Paint event:

```
e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen1, 0.0F, 0.0F, 200.0F, 200.0F)
```

That works, but how can I add an event handler for that graphics that I've just drawn?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That graphics is not an object that you instantiate and that could raise events. It is just a graphics primitive. You should build a usercontrol that has the capability to draw itself and raise an event. I am dubious that this worth the trouble

Comment: I know it's not an object to instanciate. That's why I wondered if it was somehow possible. Anyway, I guess a userControl should work, I'll give it a try, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can have one event raise another event.  Lets start with a basic form that uses a GraphicsPath to store the shape and paints it:

```
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Public Class Form1

    Private Shape As GraphicsPath

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Shape = New GraphicsPath()
        Shape.AddEllipse(0, 0, 200.0F, 200.0F)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Black, Shape)
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now you want to add an event so that some other class can see the shape being clicked:

```
Public Event ShapeClick As EventHandler
```

You write a protected virtual method that raises the event, part of the standard .NET event raising pattern:

```
Protected Overridable Sub OnShapeClick(ByVal e As EventArgs)
    '--- Note: you can write code here to respond to the click
    RaiseEvent ShapeClick(Me, e)
End Sub
```

And you need to pay attention to the user clicking on the form.  You'll check if the shape was clicked and raise the event if that was the case:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseUp(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    If Shape.IsVisible(e.Location) Then OnShapeClick(EventArgs.Empty)
    MyBase.OnMouseUp(e)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could intercept the windows or views (etc..., i don't know what you are using) click event, so every time you click somewhere that function will be called.

And in that click event check if it is inside your custom drawn element. You will need to save the elements properties first though and it would use a lot of resources to iterate through all the elements.

I don't know if this is acceptable in your case or not and what you are actually trying to accomplish.